# Visual Studio Online: Nuget Package restore fails

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package-restore

I'm setting up continuous deploy on Visual Studio Online and my first task is to restore Nuget package.

I have a private feed that requires Nuget client v3.4+.

`Visual Studio online task gives me this output:
2017-03-10T13:39:25.2130485Z ##[section]Starting: NuGet restore **/*.sln
2017-03-10T13:39:25.2620473Z ==============================================================================
2017-03-10T13:39:25.2620473Z Task         : NuGet Installer
2017-03-10T13:39:25.2620473Z Description  : Installs or restores missing NuGet packages
2017-03-10T13:39:25.2620473Z Version      : 0.2.29
2017-03-10T13:39:25.2620473Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2017-03-10T13:39:25.2620473Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)
2017-03-10T13:39:25.2620473Z ==============================================================================
2017-03-10T13:39:26.5963540Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
2017-03-10T13:39:26.6283512Z Active code page: 65001
2017-03-10T13:39:26.7953529Z Detected NuGet version 3.3.0.212 / 3.3.0`

Is there a way to use a newer version of the client with this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was just under my eyes

In the nuget package restore task there is an Advanced colapse field.

Open it and you can chose nuget 3.5!

[image: Advanced collapse field]